# AWSLex GetSlotType API . Error in fetching the latest version of SlotType

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am new to AWSLex. I was trying to fetch the SlotType information through ModelBuilding GetSlotType API.
The request URL: GET /slottypes/name/versions/version HTTP/1.1 
To fetch the latest version as per document is Pattern: \$LATEST|[0-9]+

Through Postman I am able to execute with version number.But while fetching the latest version $LATEST, the URL I used is 
https://models.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/slottypes/serviceType/versions/%24LATEST
which worked perfectly through Postman.

The same url when I had used to create the signature didn't work. I get following error

"*The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.*"

The canonical request what I had generated is below

```
   GET
   /slottypes/serviceType/versions/%24LATEST

   content-type:application/json
   host:models.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   x-amz-date:20180809T052553Z

   content-type;host;x-amz-date
   e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Any help on how to fix the issue is highly appreciated.

```
 String payloadHash = CommonUtil.hexEncode(sha256Hash(payload));
 ZonedDateTime utcNow = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);// Date 
 for headers and the credential string
 String amzDate = 
 utcNow.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"));
  String dateStamp = 
  utcNow.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
 String canonicalHeaders = String.format("content-type:%s\nhost:%s\nx- 
  amz-date:%s\n", contentType, host, amzDate);
 String canonicalRequest = String.format("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", 
 method, canonicalUri, canonicalQueryString, canonicalHeaders, 
 signedHeaders, payloadHash);
  String credentialScope = String.format("%s/%s/%s/aws4_request", 
  dateStamp, region, service);
  String canonicalRequestHash = 
   CommonUtil.hexEncode(sha256Hash(canonicalRequest));
   String stringToSign = String.format("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", algorithm, 
   amzDate, credentialScope, canonicalRequestHash);
  byte[] signatureKey = CommonUtil.getSignatureKey(secretKey, 
   dateStamp, region, service);
  String signature = CommonUtil.hexEncode(CommonUtil.HmacSHA256(URLEncoder.encode(stringToSign,"utf-8"), signatureKey));
   String authorizationHeader = String.format("%s Credential=%s/%s, SignedHeaders=%s, Signature=%s", algorithm, accessKey, credentialScope, signedHeaders, signature);

MultivaluedMap<String, String> headersMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
headersMap.add("Content-Type", contentType);
headersMap.add("X-Amz-Date", amzDate);
headersMap.add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
```

This is how I am generating the signature.The same code works fine with version as number. The issue lies when I encode the url with $LATEST as value and pass it.

Comment: Can you show us how the request was built? It seems that Amazon does not like part of the process which signed the request with your API keys.

Comment: I have updated the question with how I built the request.